# How Create two or more rectangles in on space of canvas proportionally?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, draw

guys!

I have a problem.

I want create on, two or more rectangles in a space proportionally.
So, a have the canvas in 600x800px and I have a rectangle in 200x400px, I need when I click in a button, create more one rectangle in the some space of other. staying, 100x200 and 100x200 for both rectangles.

Some one?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to show attempt.  Post code that you have tried and we will help you if you hit a snag.  What problems are you having?

Comment: Maybe you can add a picture of what the desired result looks like

Comment: this is the screen: http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/000/158/026/original/on.png?1389803984 when a click the button "Add" make this: http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/000/158/029/original/two.png?1389804018, and when a click the button "Add" again, make this: http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/000/158/032/original/three.png?1389804041..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is:

- Keep a Y-coordinate variable,
- Draw your next rectangle at that Y,
- Increment Y by the rectangle height (plus any spacing between rects that you desire)

Here's code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/czMXH/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var y=10;
    var spacer=8;

    $("#again").click(function(){

        ctx.fillStyle=randomColor();
        ctx.fillRect(10,y,100,66);
        ctx.strokeStyle="black";
        ctx.strokeRect(10,y,100,66);
        y+=66+spacer;

    });

    function randomColor(){ 
        return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="again">Add</button><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is nearly so. let's just say that the first rectangle is 200x400 height and width when I click the "Add" button, the space that occupies the first rectangle will be divided for the two rectangles, each being 100x400, and so on. so let's assume I have a space of only 200x400 and I can not get over it. the rectangles have to fit the space proportionally. Thanks!

Comment: Here's how to subdivide a fixed area into an increasing number of rectangles: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/C3qnf/

Comment: Perfect, that's right! But, you remove and create again. and if I create a text with the rectangle? the text would decrease proportionally with the rectangle?

Comment: Yes, redrawing is the only way to re-divide the space.  If you're drawing text you will have to scale the font size when the rectangles get shorter.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help. So you can, I'll post the code here as it got. Thank you all! ;)